# PC freezes when HDMI monitor is turned off

Tags: hdmi, windows-server-2008-r2, dvi, amd-radeon

All screens go black and PC freezes when I turn off a monitor connected by HDMI.  I can tell that it's frozen since NumLock does not toggle any more.  Power-cycling the PC brings things back to normal.

Details:
I have three Dell U2711 27" monitors connected.  Two are connected via dual-link DVI, and one via 100 ft HDMI cable with a built-in signal booster by KanexPro.  All three go through a Radeon HD 6xxx graphics card into a PC with redundant 750W power supplies.

All screens are running at 1650x1050, with one DVI-connected screen duplicated to HDMI-connected screen.

Latest BIOS and drivers throughout.

*EDIT* 100-ft cable has signal booster built-in.  I connected input end to the graphics card and output end to the 27" LCD.

All works well with a short 3 ft HDMI cable.

Comment: operating system?

Comment: Is it the monitor on the extender that causes the freeze?

Comment: @MalwareManiac it's Server 2008 R2.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz please see my edits to the question.